# ¿Es correcto usar "iniciar" en "¿cuándo iniciará Navidad?"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos

Leyendo [una pregunta en Meta Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1159/83) vi que el título era:

> Llegó diciembre 2016, ¿cuándo **iniciará** el Winter Bash?

Me sonó rarísimo para mí que hablo castellano de España, por lo que inmediatamente lo cambié por *comenzará*: *¿cuándo comenzará el Winter Bash?*

Sin embargo, me quedé con la duda y busqué en el DRAE, que me explica:

> [**iniciar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LcKjRTa)
>   *Del lat. initiāre.*
>   1. tr. comenzar (‖ dar principio a algo). Iniciar la marcha, la sesión.
>   2. tr. Introducir o instruir a alguien en la práctica de un culto o en las reglas de una sociedad, especialmente si se considera secreta o misteriosa. Lo iniciaron en aquel culto ancestral. U. t. c. prnl.
>   3. tr. Proporcionar a alguien los primeros conocimientos o experiencias sobre algo. Su mentora lo inició en el arte desde muy pequeño. U. t. c. prnl.
>   4. prnl. Dar comienzo. Fue allí donde se inició el incendio.

Descarto la cuarta acepción en este contexto pues tiene valor pronominal, que no es el caso. En este caso sería la primera la que aplica, en la que actúa como verbo transitivo en calidad de sinónimo de comenzar. Por tanto, parece que mi intuición falló y que es correcto... pero sigo sin verlo.

¿Es correcto? ¿Se usa corrientemente en algún lugar de habla hispana?

Comment: Para mí, el significado es precisamente el de la 4ª acepción y, por tanto, debería ser pronominal. Por tanto, la frase original es incorrecta.

Comment: Es interesante lo que dice rsanchez que en el DRAE iniciar no aparece como intr. pero por latinoamérica **iniciar, comenzar** y **empezar** son "_completamente_" sinónimos y la gente los usa de igual manera.  Aquí no suena nada extraño.

Comment: @DGaleano esta es una muy buena adición. La persona que preguntó creo que es de México, por lo que resulta muy relevante este matiz. De todos modos, el diccionario de americanismos no lo menciona y [el diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=MmXkdiNcyD6MIjteji) indica que _No es correcto su uso como intransitivo no pronominal: La semana inició mal, error debido al cruce con el verbo sinónimo empezar, que sí admite esta construcción_.

Comment: La RAE es todo menos consistente en cuanto a adoptar palabras y usos pero esta es una que debían haber adoptado hace mucho tiempo ya que su uso en latinoamérica es muy extendido y frecuente.

Comment: @DGaleano entiendo pues que debería ser cuestión de [poco] tiempo que la incluyan. ¿Sabes si se usa en toooda Hispanoamérica?

Comment: No podría jurar que se usa en toooda hispanoamérica pero viendo el canal FoxSporstLA pienso que en Argentina, Chile, Colombia, Venezuela, Panamá y México es de uso frecuente. Tengo poco contacto con el español Boliviano, Peruano, Ecuatoriano y Centroamericano. Ya tenemos confirmado México en tu pregunta y se que en Colombia mucha gente usa iniciar y comenzar como sinónimos. Ojalá alguien de los otros países lo confirme o lo niegue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se te guías por lo que dice el DRAE, no es correcto. Justamente allí dice que *iniciar* es equivalente a *comenzar* en su uso transitivo, pero en la oración que citas el uso es intransitivo: *el Winter Bash* es el sujeto, y no hay objeto directo ni indirecto.

El uso intransitivo de *comenzar* sí está recogido por el DRAE:

> **comenzar**
>
> 1. tr. **empezar** (‖ dar principio).
> 2. intr. Dicho de una cosa: **empezar** (‖ tener principio). *Ahora comienza la misa. Aquí comienza el tratado.*

Desconozco si más allá de lo que diga el diccionario *iniciar* se usa de esa manera en algún lugar, al menos a mí también me suena extraño.